# Problem with Chrome on 18.04 LTS

Tags: google-chrome

When I go to the website cnnlivestream.com using Chrome, Version 67.0.3396.87 (Official Build) (64-bit), I get a Privacy Error.

"Your connection is not private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from cnnlivestream.com"

If I try that on FireFox version 60.02 it works fine.  Also works fine on Windows 10 using Chrome (latest version).

Does anyone know what might be happening?

Thanks.

Comment: It worked, thanks!  Not sure why but at least I don't need 2 browsers open now, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearing temporary data like cookies and cache might help.

Since when you use a browser, like Chrome, it saves some information from websites in its cache and cookies. Clearing them fixes certain problems, like loading or formatting issues on sites.

Alternatively, if you just want to be confident that the issue isn't with connection, try opening website in Incognito mode.